# Where to find ipc (or cpi) value of Intel processors (say skylake) when diff no of physical and logical cores are used?

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-architecture, hpc, microbenchmark

I am very new to this field and my question might be too stupid but please help me understand the fundamental here.

I want to know the instruction per cycle (ipc) or clock per instruction (cpi) of recent intel processors such as skylake or cascade lake. And I am also looking for these values when different no of physical cores are used and when hyper threading is used.

I thought spec cpu2017 benchmark results could help me here, but I could not find my ans there. They just compare the total execution time by time taken by some reference machine and gives the ratio. Am I missing something here?

I thought this is one of the very first performance parameters and should be calculated and published by some standard benchmark, but I could not find any. Am I missing something here?

Another related question which comes to my mind (and I think everybody might want to know) is what is the best it can provide using all the cores and threads (least cpi and max ipc)?

Please help me find ipc / cpi value of skylake (any Intel processor) when say maximum (28) cores are used and when hyperthreading is also enabled.

Comment: You've already posted the part on how to measure IPC as a separate question, so you can remove it from this one and change the title to something like "what is the max ipc?" I'll answer your questions as soon as I can.

Answer (score 1):

The IPC cost of hyperthreading (or SMT in general on non-Intel CPUs) totally depends on the workload.

If you're already bottlenecked on branch mispredicts, cache misses, or long dependency chains (low ILP), having 2 threads running on the same core leads to minimal interference.

(Partitioning the ROB reduces the ability to find ILP in either thread, though, so again it depends on the details.)

Competitive sharing of uop cache and L1d/L1i / L2 caches also might or might not be a problem, depending on cache footprint.

### There is no general answer independent of workload

Some workloads get a major speedup from using HT to double the number of logical cores.  Some high-ILP workloads actually do worse because of cache conflicts.  (Workloads that can already come close to saturating the front-end at 4 uops per clock on Intel before Icelake, for example).

Agner Fog's microarch guide says a bit about this for some microarchitectures that support hyperthreading.  https://agner.org/optimize/

IIRC, some AMD CPUs have higher front-end throughput with hyperthreading, but I think only Bulldozer-family.

---

**Max throughput** is not affected by HT, and each core is independent.  e.g. 4 uops per clock for a Skylake core.  Doubling the number of physical cores always doubles theoretical uops / clock.  Obviously not all workloads parallelize efficiently, so running more threads might need more total instructions/uops, and/or create more memory stalls for communication.

Hyperthreading just helps you come closer to that more of the time by letting 2 threads fill each other's "bubbles" from stalls.

Comment: Thank you sir. One more follow up (stupid) question. Please help me here also. How should "4 uops per clock" be mapped to no of instructions to get max (theoratical) ipc (say for int as well as float workloads).

Comment: @user3488903 1 instruction -> at least 1 fused-domain uop, except for macro-fusion of compare+branch which lets modern Intel CPUs run up to 6 instructions per clock.  But usually exactly 1 uop per instruction, including for `vfmaddps` 256-bit FMA instructions.  Of course back-end throughput (2/clock vector FMA or add or mul) is the theoretical bottleneck for FP math on Intel CPUs, not front-end throughput.  But load/store / loop overhead can eat up the other 2 uops.

Comment: One way to think of macro-fusion (cmp/jcc decoding to 1 uop) is that it introduces a way to cmp/branch with only 1 uop, reducing your program's actual "instruction" count if you want to use an IPC model instead of uops/clock model.  Of course it's very rare for real code to sustain 4 fused-domain uops per clock, and also fairly rare to saturate the SIMD FMA units.  A well-tuned matmul can sometimes do the latter.

Comment: @user3488903: I did some testing a while ago on Haswell and Skylake to identify unfused-domain uop throughput limits (using micro-fusion of memory source or destination operands to get up to 7 back-end uops packed into 4 front-end uops, and getting those to all execute at 1 per clock):  https://www.agner.org/optimize/blog/read.php?i=415#857

Comment: @user3488903: But anyway, since Haswell the max theoretical throughput is 6 instructions per clock, in a loop with a not-taken and a taken branch.  The other 2 uops can be whatever you want, although it will bottleneck on the back-end if they're both FP math.  The not-taken-branch execution unit on Haswell/Skylake is on port 0, the same port as one of the FMA units.  But FP bitwise operations like `xorps` to flip the sign bit can run on port 5, and load or store are separate.  And of course this could be part of a larger loop with lots of perfectly-predicted branching.

Comment: @user3488903: **theoretical-max discussions are mostly useless**.  Practical IPC has climbed quite a lot from Sandybridge to Skylake, but theoretical max IPC / uop throughput hasn't changed except for Haswell adding another execution unit for not-taken branches and decoders that can make 2 fusions in the same decode group.

Comment: Sir, thanks for taking time to explain. Regarding, "Practical IPC has climbed quite a lot from Sandybridge to Skylake" are there some max practical ipc nos (on max cores) on any workload published somewhere? What are the max practical IPCs attained by these processors on any possible workload. Please help.

Comment: @user3488903: x264 and x265 video encoding run pretty high IPC on Skylake.  Try it with `perf stat`.  IIRC, I got well over 3 uops/clock, maybe closer to 3.5.  Why do you care?  What are you hoping to do with this information?  When I said "practical", I meant on real workloads like SPECint / SPECfp where performance is limited by stalls and stuff, and extracting the available ILP is harder.  If you ultimately want to make your own code run faster, you're asking the wrong questions.

Comment: Sir, initially i was hoping to get some observed/measured IPC values from spec cpu2017 (int and float) benchmark results, but I found that they just report ratio (as i mentioned in my original question) and not IPC values. Am I missing something here? Can IPC value be retrieved/derived from SPEC benchmark results? (Sir, it all started when I started doing some math on Amdahl balanced law (8 MIPS =1Mbps), but  may be that wil be a new thread).

Comment: @user3488903 No, IPC can't be derived from speed because you don't know the average CPU utilization (# of cores active) or the instruction count.  Some researchers ran SPECint and SPECfp 2017 under `perf stat` to get IPC number on a Skylake CPU.  (Actually CPI, the reciprocal).  http://lca.ece.utexas.edu/pubs/UT_LCA_TR-180515-01.pdf  The SPECrate benchmarks are with multiple copies of the benchmark running on multiple cores, instead of auto-parallelizing the benchmarks or running single-threaded.

Comment: Sir, acually I referred this paper before This paper measured IPC values on single core system. What should we expect of IPC value when all (or more) cores will be used?

Comment: By approximation, can we multiply measured IPC value by no of cores used? But that would be too high and surely incorrect. What rough estimate can be infer of (max possible) IPC value from this paper. (Frankly speaking, I am having sleepless nights over this question).

Comment: @user3488903:  The paper says they tested on an i7-6700, which is a 4c / 8t CPU.  They also tested on a 6-core (12 thread) Xeon.  Search for "core" in the paper.  IPC is usually measured per core, treating each core as having its own cycles as well as its own instructions.  (On a Xeon each core's clock is even independent so you can't argue that there's one global clock.)  So N threads all running at 3 IPC on N cores is still an average IPC of 3.

Comment: @user3488903: *What rough estimate can be infer of (max possible) IPC value from this paper*  You can't infer anything of the sort because none of the SPEC benchmarks are synthetic or designed to expose a ton of ILP and benefit from really wide CPUs.  It's possible to write a loop that in practice runs 6 x86 instructions per clock on a real Haswell or Skylake CPU.  It's all a question of where you draw the line between a synthetic microbenchmark vs. a real-world benchmark.